# How do I set up the speaker on a HCS12 microcontroller?

Tags: button, assembly, microcontroller, speaker

Basically, my microcontroller is supposed to play a sound based on the push buttons (PTH) I press and light up the LED (PORTB). What I am stuck on is how to set up the speaker to output sound when the push buttons are pressed. A lot of the code is based off code from here: http://www.microdigitaled.com/HCS12/Hardware/Dragon12-Plus-Support.htm

Specifically the link about the buzzer. Also when I use the code provided I am able to hear sound coming from my microcontroller; however not when I try to include the push button into the code.

I would greatly appreciate any hints, comments, tips, or suggestions. Thank you so much!

Here is my code so far:

```
;----------------------USE $1000-$2FFF for Scratch Pad
R1      EQU     $1001
R2      EQU     $1002
R3      EQU     $1003
R4      EQU     $1004

;code section
    ORG   $2000     ;Flash ROM address for Dragon12+
Entry:
      LDS     #$2000    ;Stack
      BSET    DDRT,%00100000     ;PTT5 as Output pin for buzzer
      BSET    DDRP,#$0F   ; Set Port P pins 0-3 to output
      BSET    PTP, #$0F     ; Disable 7-Segment Display
      ; LED
      BSET    DDRB,$FF
      BSET    DDRJ,$02
      BCLR    PTJ,$02

      ; PBs
      BCLR    DDRH,$0F
      BCLR    PTH,$FF       ;PORTB as Output

;-------Sound the Buzzer at PTT5

BACK          
;-------Get data from DIP switches connected to PORTH and send it to LEDs of PORTB

 ;how is the speaker supposed to be set up? because when I try the code the speaker does not output any sound.

      LDAA PTH        ;Get data from DIP Switches of PTH
      STAA PORTB      ;and send it to PORTB
      BSET PTT,%00100000     ;PTT5=1
      JSR DELAY        
      BCLR PTT,%00100000     ;PTT5=0
      JSR DELAY        
      BRA BACK              ;Keep toggling buzzer
```

Is my delay okay? Am I on the right track or is there a more convenient way of changing the notes?

```
;----------DELAY
DELAY
    COMA
    TSTA
    CMPA    #$01
    BNE     no_note1
    PSHA        ;Save Reg A on Stack
    LDAA    #7        ;Change this value to hear  
    STAA    R3        ;different Buzzer sounds
;--1 msec delay. The Serial Monitor works at speed of 48MHz with XTAL=8MHz on Dragon12+ board
;Freq. for Instruction Clock Cycle is 24MHz (1/2 of 48Mhz).
;(1/24MHz) x 10 Clk x240x10=1 msec. Overheads are excluded in this calculation.       
L3      LDAA    #10
    STAA    R2    
L2      LDAA    #200
    STAA    R1
L1      NOP         ;1 Intruction Clk Cycle
    NOP         ;1
    NOP         ;1
    DEC     R1  ;4
    BNE     L1  ;3
    DEC     R2  ;Total Instr.Clk=10
    BNE     L2
    DEC     R3
    BNE     L3
    PULA            ;Restore Reg A
no_note1:        
    CMPA    #$02
    BNE     no_note2
    PSHA        ;Save Reg A on Stack
    LDAA    #3        ;Change this value to hear  
    STAA    R3        ;different Buzzer sounds
;--1 msec delay. The Serial Monitor works at speed of 48MHz with XTAL=8MHz on Dragon12+ board
;Freq. for Instruction Clock Cycle is 24MHz (1/2 of 48Mhz).
;(1/24MHz) x 10 Clk x240x10=1 msec. Overheads are excluded in this calculation.       
L9        LDAA    #10
    STAA    R2    
L8        LDAA    #210
    STAA    R1
L7      NOP         ;1 Intruction Clk Cycle
    NOP         ;1
    NOP         ;1
    DEC     R1  ;4
    BNE     L7  ;3
    DEC     R2  ;Total Instr.Clk=10
    BNE     L8
    DEC     R3
    BNE     L9
    PULA            ;Restore Reg A
no_note2:
    CMPA    #$04
    BNE     no_note3
    PSHA        ;Save Reg A on Stack
    LDAA    #2        ;Change this value to hear  
    STAA    R3        ;different Buzzer sounds
;--1 msec delay. The Serial Monitor works at speed of 48MHz with XTAL=8MHz on Dragon12+ board
;Freq. for Instruction Clock Cycle is 24MHz (1/2 of 48Mhz).
;(1/24MHz) x 10 Clk x240x10=1 msec. Overheads are excluded in this calculation.       
L4        LDAA    #15
    STAA    R2    
L5        LDAA    #240
    STAA    R1
L6      NOP         ;1 Intruction Clk Cycle
    NOP         ;1
    NOP         ;1
    DEC     R1  ;4
    BNE     L6  ;3
    DEC     R2  ;Total Instr.Clk=10
    BNE     L5
    DEC     R3
    BNE     L4
    PULA            ;Restore Reg A
no_note3:        
    CMPA    #$08
    BNE     no_note4
    PSHA        ;Save Reg A on Stack
    LDAA    #9        ;Change this value to hear  
    STAA    R3        ;different Buzzer sounds
;--1 msec delay. The Serial Monitor works at speed of 48MHz with XTAL=8MHz on Dragon12+ board
;Freq. for Instruction Clock Cycle is 24MHz (1/2 of 48Mhz).
;(1/24MHz) x 10 Clk x240x10=1 msec. Overheads are excluded in this calculation.       
L30     LDAA    #16
    STAA    R2    
L20     LDAA    #249
    STAA    R1
L10     NOP         ;1 Intruction Clk Cycle
    NOP         ;1
    NOP         ;1
    DEC     R1  ;4
    BNE     L10  ;3
    DEC     R2  ;Total Instr.Clk=10
    BNE     L20
    DEC     R3
    BNE     L30
;--------------        
    PULA            ;Restore Reg A
no_note4:
    RTS
;-------------------

;----------------------------------------------------
; Interrupt Vector
;----------------------------------------------------
      ; Port H Vector
      ; $3E4C = $FFCC - $C180
      ORG     $3E4C
      FDB     DELAY
FINISH:
NOP
    END
```

Comment: moving this too-often-copied delay into a subfunction could help reading your code. Afaik the HCS12 has a timer interrupt that could be used to turn the buzzer on/off at the right frequency

Comment: So instead of a subroutine change it into a function?

Comment: I got it thanks!
just changed the JSR to BSR